# Displaying a table using react components - Is this the right way to display a table?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im trying to create a very basic table view of bootstrap and displaying the rows using local state values .

I just want to understand if this is the correct way to display a table in react .

````
Row Component 
```import React, { Component } from "react";
class Human extends Component {
  render() {
    const { humans } = this.props;
    return humans.map(human => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{human.id}</th>
          <td>{human.name}</td>
          <td>{human.designation}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
}

export default Human;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Human from "./human";

class HumanListing extends Component {
  state = {
    humans: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "titus",
        designation: "main"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "titus2",
        designation: "main2"
      }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    const { humans } = this.state;
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <Human humans={humans} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default HumanListing;
```
````

There arent any error messages , apart from that i get a warning message mentioning that key has to be included for each list value

Comment: This infact gets me the result i want , just curious to know if this is the right way or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you map a items, need to assign key

```
return humans.map((human,key) => {
  return (
    <tr key={key}>
      <th scope="row">{human.id}</th>
      <td>{human.name}</td>
      <td>{human.designation}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

and i think it's fine for you the table, but im no sure with Class `Human` maybe `HumanRows` fit better because that class return a rows of table. its my opinion,
of course exist many ways to do the same thing but yours look good.